# Minimal sum of matrix elements

Tags: reference-request, optimization, terminology

Here's my attempt to explain the problem in mathematical language:

$$
\text{Given square matrix A}
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,N} \\
 a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,N} \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 a_{N,1} & a_{N,2} & \cdots & a_{N,N}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Find a minimal sum of $N$ elements such that no two elements are in the same row or column. In other words, find $$\min_{\sigma\in S_N}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^Na_{i,\sigma(i)}\right\},$$ where $S_N$ is the set of permutations on $\{1,\ldots,N\}$.

Is there a standard name for this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called the [(linear) assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). It can be solved efficiently through linear programming over the Birkhoff polytope.